# FrontEnd-Login with CouchDB

Tags: javascript, authentication, nosql, couchdb

What is the best approach for developing a web-application with CouchDB, in which front-end-users have to log in [for example a forum]? For this, i need some authentication-mechanism for checking username/password and storing them in a session/cookie.

How can i realize that in CouchDB? Is there a way to run server-side code directly on the couch? Do I need an additional software-component like node.js or a php-interpreter?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Superlogin is a new NodeJS login framework that supports CouchDb logins.

I've recently integrated this new Authentication API into one of my mobile apps and it was very easy to do. The clear documentation and demo app code were excellent kick starters. Although only newly open sourced, the code maturity and test coverage feels like it's been used in production for a while. The developer has been very helpful and responsive.

- Extensive server API and Optional Angular client API.
- Comprehensive demo app.
- Supports local username/password, password reset, password update, user profile updating.
- Attach any number of social OAuth logins (Facebook, Twitter, Google etc) per user account. Uses [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/) that support over 300 authentication plugins.
- Can integrate [SendGrid API](https://sendgrid.com/) to verify emails and send other user event notifications
- Generates temporary long and random CouchDb user/passwords per user session
  so you can still replicate into PouchDb using Basic Auth directly to the CouchDb server but with significantly improved security.
- 100% cookie free, preventing CSRF attacks
- Fast and scalable with optional Redis session store
- Comprehensive test suite.

Fully open source and MIT licence:

- [Superlogin Server](https://github.com/colinskow/superlogin)
- [NG Superlogin Client](https://github.com/colinskow/ng-superlogin)
- [Superlogin Demo App](https://github.com/colinskow/superlogin-demo) | [Live Demo](http://superlogin-demo.herokuapp.com)

Answer (score 1):

You now want to check out the new Hoodie project at http://Hood.ie .

It includes an API to manage CouchDb user accounts including:

```
// sign up
hoodie.account.signUp('joe@example.com', 'secret');

// sign in
hoodie.account.signIn('joe@example.com', 'secret');

// sign out
hoodie.account.signOut();

// change password
hoodie.account.changePassword('currentpassword', 'newpassword');

// change username
hoodie.account.changeUsername('currentpassword', 'newusername');

// reset password
hoodie.account.resetPassword('joe@example.com');

// destroy account and all its data
hoodie.account.destroy();

// find out who the currently logged in user is (returns undefined if none)
hoodie.account.username;
```

And events ...

```
// user has signed up (this also triggers the authenticated event, see below)
hoodie.account.on('signup', function (user) {});

// user has signed in (this also triggers the authenticated event, see below)
hoodie.account.on('signin', function (user) {});

// user has signed out
hoodie.account.on('signout', function (user) {});

// user has re-authenticated after their session timed out (this does _not_ trigger the signin event)
hoodie.account.on('authenticated', function (user) {});

// user's session has timed out. This means the user is still signed in locally, but Hoodie cannot sync remotely, so the user must sign in again
hoodie.account.on('unauthenticated', function (user) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no direct experience with couchDB, as far as I know its a database, meaning that you will definitely need a server side language to interface with it from the browser. Node.js and php are possible choices in that case (although I think couchdb has extremely good support for node.js, although I might be mistaken). Either way, here there is a possible setup within node.js: http://artem.posterous.com/nodejs-authentication-with-couchdb-and-expres

Comment: Thanks for your response. CouchDB can directly deliver HTML and build complete apps on its own with its build-in show and list-functions. 

Have a look here (the app):
http://couchbuch.iriscouch.com/kassenbuch/_design/buchhaltung/index.html
and here (the couch)
http://couchbuch.iriscouch.com/_utils/document.html?kassenbuch/_design/buchhaltung

And of course, you can poll the views, you have defined with the map/reduce-functions via simple JavaScript. But i cant find anything to run simple server-side-code.

Comment: My bad my bad, I knew that we looked into couchDB vs mongoDB for our noSQL solution we offer to our clients, although I only was part of exploring mongoDB after the choice was already made, so I assumed that couchDB was fairly similar in it's set up. In that case I hope somebody will be able to give you a more relevant answer.

Comment: no, it's not true, you can use but you don't need any server side language to interface with CouchDB in view of it's nature. see http://couchdb.apache.org/ : '''CouchDB is a database that completely embraces the web. Store your data with JSON documents. Access your documents with your web browser, via HTTP. Query, combine, and transform your documents with JavaScript.'''

Answer (score 0):

Couchdb can handle this for you.  It will do couch level authentication and database level authentication.
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview

Basically there is a _users db that has all your users and you can set users in a _security document to protect the database.

For document level security you have to role your own.  I've been told this is not recommended and database per user model is favored here.

You can also use BrowserID (Persona)
https://github.com/iriscouch/browserid_couchdb

Kan.so has some nice packages for creating users from the front end if you are building a couchapp and would like some package management.